# templates and returning a node*

Tags: c++, templates, return-type

I am making a BST class with template types for the key, data and a comparison function. I have a function that creates new nodes and returns a pointer to other functions. The problem is, the return type is not valid while using templates. I have created trees previously without templates and returning a type node* wasn't an issue. I'm not sure of what is happening behind the scenes to make the template version not work. 
The errors I'm getting include:

unrecognizable template declaration/definition

syntax error: missing ';' before '*'

missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

My class template, node struct and node create function are below:

```
template <typename KEY, typename VALUE, bool (*COMPARE)(KEY, KEY )>
class BSTROOT {

private:
    struct Node {
        KEY key;
        VALUE value;
        Node *left = nullptr;
        Node *right = nullptr;
    };
    Node* createNode(const KEY& key, const VALUE& value);



template <typename KEY, typename VALUE, bool(*COMPARE)(KEY, KEY)> Node* BSTROOT<KEY, VALUE, COMPARE>::createNode(const KEY& key, const VALUE& value) {
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->key = key;
    temp->value = value;
    return temp;
}
```

Any tips or information would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you close the class definition with `};`?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: All of my {} are good, I didn't do a straight copy paste of all the code just the bits I thought were relevant. I figured I shouldn't dump a huge chunk of code onto the page. My first time asking a question here so forgive me if I don't do whats usually expected

Comment: Just as a comment, your comparison function should take const key references rather than copies.

Comment: You are right that huge code chunks are not appreciated. That's why I asked for a "minimal" example.

Comment: @SoronellHaetir you're exactly right and I'll do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `Node*` type is nested inside of the `BSTROOT` type, so you need to explicitly indicate that when writing the type of the return value from the function in the implementation. That would look something like this:

```
template <typename KEY, typename VALUE, bool(*COMPARE)(KEY, KEY)>
typename BSTROOT<KEY, VALUE, COMPARE>::Node*
BSTROOT<KEY, VALUE, COMPARE>::createNode(const KEY& key, const VALUE& value) {
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->key = key;
    temp->value = value;
    return temp;
}
```

Here, the extra `typename` keyword is necessary because `Node` is what's called a *dependent type* (a type nested inside something that depends on a template parameter).

You don't need to put that long name inside the body of the class because in that context the compiler already knows to look inside of `BSTROOT`. Outside of the class, though, the compiler can't tell that you want it to look at the nested `Node` type rather than some other global type named `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

```
template <typename KEY, typename VALUE, bool(*COMPARE)(KEY, KEY)>
struct Node {
    KEY key;
    VALUE value;
    Node *left = nullptr;
    Node *right = nullptr;
};

template <typename KEY, typename VALUE, bool(*COMPARE)(KEY, KEY)>
class BSTROOT {

private:

    Node* createNode(const KEY& key, const VALUE& value);


};

template<typename KEY, typename VALUE, bool(*COMPARE)(KEY, KEY)>
Node * BSTROOT<KEY, VALUE, COMPARE>::createNode(const KEY & key, const VALUE & value)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->key = key;
    temp->value = value;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: This code won't compile - you need to specify the template arguments to the `Node` type. Also, this exposes the internal implementation of the `Node` type to the outside world, which breaks the encapsulation of the current system. Though perhaps there is an advantage that I'm missing?